# can't serve static html files in golang

Tags: html, go

I am trying to follow an online video course on golang and I am getting an error serving static html files.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", new(MyHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

type MyHandler struct {
    http.Handler
}

func (this *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := "public/" + req.URL.Path
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(path))

    if err == nil {
        w.Write(data)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        w.Write([]byte("404 - " + http.StatusText(404)))
    }
}
```

My folder structure
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBF6t.png).

Comment: path := "public/" + req.URL.Path   path set incorrect. Simplest way would be absolute rooted path for public.

Comment: but the instructor seems to have it working, can you please give me the link how to make it right ?

Comment: @Shavkat are you running the executable from where you think you are? BTW your instructor's code is really non idiomatic.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer i just can't  access /html/home.html file i get 404

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link to your folder structure I'm going to guess that you need `path := "../public/" + req.URL.Path`. Your application is running from the `bin` directory so you can't go directly into a sibling directory, you need `..` to go out one directory at which point `public` is actually an option.

Comment: it can find no file even home page is 404 not found

Comment: @Shavkat well it's not going to find anything in the `bin` or in `bin/public` because that folder doesn't exist. It needs to look in `../public`. That or the applications current working directory at the time of the read is not the `bin` as I am assuming in which case try an absolute path/figure out what your CWD is and then make your path from there. The only problem here is that your path is **definitely** wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Correct path is ../../public, because your main.go file is in main/src folder.